# Why this program dosen't halt when only need to iterating throught a finite stream?

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to get a list of primes of two digits by running these codes in LearnOcaml.  The codes compile if I restrict the parameter of the listify method, which returns a list from a stream, to be less than 20. Otherwise, it either never halt or return "Exception: Js_of_ocaml__Js.Error _.". I don't think the code is semantically wrong. So I'm 
wondering if anyone can help resolve the problem?

```
type 'a stream = Eos | StrCons of 'a*(unit -> 'a stream)



(*integers from n onwards*)
let rec nums_from n =
  StrCons(n,fun () -> nums_from (n+1))



let rec filterStr (test : 'a -> bool) (s: 'a stream) =
  match s with
  |Eos -> Eos
  |StrCons(q,w) -> if test q then StrCons(q,fun ()-> filterStr test (w ()))
      else filterStr test (w ())  

(*Remove all numbers mod p*)
let sift p =
  filterStr (fun x -> x mod p <> 0)

(*Sieves*)
let rec sieves s =
  match s with
  |Eos ->Eos
  |StrCons(x,g) -> StrCons(x, fun ()-> sieves (sift x (g ())))


(*primes*) 
let allprimes = sieves (nums_from 2) 

let rec listify s n=
  if n =0 then [] else
    match s with
    |Eos -> []
    |StrCons(q,w) -> q::(listify (w ()) (n-1))

let twodigitsprimes = filterStr (fun x -> x > 10&& x<100) allprimes

let twodigitsprimeslist= listify twodigitsprimes 21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `filterStr` is looping while trying to create the `StrCons` that represents the next element after the 21st. Since there are only 21 2-digit primes, this will loop forever.

Note that when `listify` is called with n = 0, the `StrCons` has already been constructed; it just isn't examined. But the `StrCons` for this case diverges (and OCaml is a strict language).

You can get things to work using this version of `listify`:

```
let rec listify s n =
  if n = 0 then []
  else
    match s with
    | Eos -> []
    | StrCons (q, w) ->
        if n = 1 then [q] else q :: listify (w ()) (n - 1)
```